# Are all of the interactions between Angelina and Belle covered in the Angelina Ending?

Tags: katahane

I've been following [this walkthrough](http://tlwiki.org/index.php?title=Katahane%3aWalkthrough) for *Katahane*, and I'm do the Angelina Ending, because I brought the game purely to see the romance between Angelina and Belle, however I do plan to get the Wakaba and Coco Endings after (since I'm a completionist).

Are all of the interactions between Angelina and Belle covered in the Angelina Ending? Are there any scenes between them that only viewable in Wakaba's and Coco's Routes?

EDIT: After completing what i think is the Angelina Ending it seems to end abruptly and the Wakaba ending seems to have more of a conclusion to Angelina and Belle, i still got to get the Coco Ending just to check but it seems that maybe the walk through might be lacking with the Angelina ending, also, my friend who made the censor patch said that there are 3 Angelina x Belle H Scenes and the logs state that it's only blocked 2 which she finds strange so she's right now looking though her code just to see if the censor patch blocked and entire section but didn't log it

Comment: Please take note that [cross-posting](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/141696/15772) is [discouraged](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141696/is-the-second-alternate-character-view-only-avaliable-after-getting-the-wakaba-e) on Stack Exchange. Ask the question on the only site you think is most applicable. If you feel that your question might not get answered on one site, please ask a moderator to migrate the question, or alternatively, delete it and re-ask it on another site.

Comment: @Krazer they're different questions, Arcade is asking about the second Alternate Character View while this one is asking about if the route i'm following is going to allow me to see every scene between Angelina and Belle to which i am now just reminded that i have forgotten to remove that note from Arcade

Comment: I have edited Arcade's question so it's clear that Arcade is asking about the mechanics of the game while this is asking about the story

Comment: So are you asking what scenes Angelina's ending unlocks or what parts of the story are covered in her ending?

Comment: @Krazer i would probably say parts of the story as you probably see parts relating to Wakaba's and Cero's developing relationship if you go for Wakaba's ending and that's solely based off from her reaction when you choose the "That's impossible" choice which is Cero asks Wakaba if it would be good to move to Silberg but according the the walkthrough Wakaba has 2 ACVs where you select Angelina which could be scenes about Angelina and Belle relationship, since it'll take me some time to check both out myself i'm asking first that's why i'm asking in case if anyone else knows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not as the Coco Ending has another scene between Angelina and Belle which can not be covered in their ending because

> Cero goes with Light to find Wakaba's script and Sylvia stay's with the girls so it's the guys who are left behind in the White Capital, this leads to Sylvia learning about Coco's ability to hide and retrieve her memories which leads to Coco remembering that Efa had entrusted her Memory Drop and the Dorn Memories with Coco (seen in the secret Kurohane chapter) and giving Efa's Memory Drop to Belle leading to Belle becoming confused in her identity and Angelina admitting her feelings to Belle and ensuring her that she loves Belle because Belle is Belle and not Efa

because of that and how the events seem to be unique to the Coco Ending i very much doubt that the Angelina Ending can cover these even if the walk-through was changed